# Numbering equation error

Tags: errors, numbering

```
\bigskip \begin{equation} $\phantom{SPACE}$ $C_{n}$  = $ \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2} $ \end{equation}
```

Will not number the equation, or even allow me to view the PDF. I am just looking for an easy way to number this equation on the right hand side.

Comment: Remove the `$` from inside the `equation` environment; remove also the `\phantom` and the `\bigskip`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. Although it has centered my equation, which luckily doesn't matter too much here with regards to the layout.

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has two mathematical modes:

- *inline mode*, where the formula is typed between `$...$` or between `\(...\)`.
- *display mode*.

When typesetting mathematics, it's better to load `amsmath`, so I'll assume it. Display math mode can be started and ended by several environments (each `\begin{...}` will be closed by a corresponding `\end{...}`, of course):

- `\begin{equation}` for numbered equations
- `\begin{equation*}` for unnumbered equations
- `\begin{gather}` for numbered clusters of equations, each occupying a line
- `\begin{gather*}` for unnumbered clusters of equations, each occupying a line
- `\begin{align}` for numbered clusters of equations, each occupying a line, but with alignment points
- `\begin{align*}` for unnumbered clusters of equations, each occupying a line, but with alignment points

There are others, see the `amsmath` manual, the LaTeX Companion or any good introduction to LaTeX.

The `equation*` environment has also the shortcut

```
\[
<equation>
\]
```

The material inside such an environment mustn't have `$` in it (unless we escape math mode with `\text`, but this is a different matter) because TeX is already in math mode.

So your code should be

```
The text that goes above the equation
\begin{equation}
  C_{n} = \frac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2}
\end{equation}
and some text after the equation.
```

No `\bigskip` before `\begin{equation}`, as LaTeX knows what spacing to use. Also `\dfrac` is not necessary, because LaTeX *is* in display math mode.

Displayed formulas/equations are normally set centered in the line, you can get left alignment (with some space to the left margin) with the `fleqn` option to `amsmath`:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

Please, have a look at an introduction to LaTeX. It's usually rewarding.